# How to initialize static const vector

Tags: c++, vector, static, initialization, constants

I have a member in my class defined like this inside my header file:

```
static const vector<note_name> noteMap;
```

In my source file I want to assign values to the vector so I tried:

```
const vector<note_name> AppSettings::noteMap = {...}
```

But I'm getting an error: `Non-aggregate type 'const vector<note_name>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list`. Any ideas how I could initialize this vector? Using an array is not an option btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function that returns a `vector<note_name>` with the appropriate values filled in, and use that function to initialize `noteMap`. That will always work; with more information about the initializers it might be possible to come up with a better solution. Or, if you have C++11, you **can** use an initializer list as in the example.

Or, with TR1 or Boost or C++11, change the `vector` to an `array<note_name>`. The `array` template supports aggregate initialization.